# print object C#

Tags: c#, list

I have this code, and I want to print the object `Persona`.
The project is called `testOggetti`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Persona p = new Persona("nome1", "cognome1", 18);
    Persona p2 = new Persona("nome2", "cognome2", 14);

    List<Persona> listaPersone = new List<Persona>();
    listaPersone.Add(p);
    listaPersone.Add(p2);

    foreach(var item in listaPersone)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

But when I try to print, the result is:

> testOggetti.Persona

Can someone tell me the reason why?

Comment: override `toString` in the `Persona` class.

Answer (score 4):

> Can someone tell me the reason why?

You get the name of *type* of the object `(testOggetti.Persona)` printed because of default implementations of the `Object.ToString` method, which returns the fully qualified name of the object's type.

Every object inherits from [Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx) in C# hence `.ToString()` is executed by default in your case `Console.WriteLine(item);`.

Simply override `.ToString()` in `Persona` class like:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("Persona: {0}, {1}, {2}", Nome, Cognome, Number);   
    // Where Nome, Cognome and Number are variables in Persona class
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the default `.ToString()` implementation on object prints out the current class' name.

Simply override ToString() in your Persona class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "Person: " + Name + " " + Age;
}
```

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) for more information.